# Inconsistent vertical spacing in section header

Tags: sectioning

My question relates to the following code due to Heiko Oberdiek:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}

%Underlining ruler for subsections
\titleformat{\section}%
  [hang]% shape
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}% format
  {}% label
  {0mm}% sep
  {%
    \vadjust pre{%
      \color{gray!50}%
      \hrule width \titlewidth height 4pt\relax
      \hrule width \linewidth height .4pt\relax
    }%
  }% before-code

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}
\section{A test section}
Text text text
\section{A test section}

\end{document}
```

This produces a specific section style, but the vertical spacing between the bar and the section title is inconsistent. To see this, you could place two sections immediately one after the other. In this example, the second section has different vertical spacing. How do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: I don't see any problem. Please, show us better.

Comment: \section{A test section} \section{A test section}
Text text text \section{A test section}

Comment: If you run this code the second section has different vertical spacing

Comment: I've added a screenshot

Comment: yes thanks can reproduce, it's an artefact of having two section headings with no actual section text between them, does that occur in your real document? If it only occurs wile drafting you could ignore it or add `TO DO` dummy text or ...

Comment: It occurs after some paragraphs too but I can't find an example of that to reproduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX's sectioning code really assumes there is some section text. Here the simplest thing to do is probably give it an invisible `\mbox{}` paragraph text and then back up by a couple of lines:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}

%Underlining ruler for subsections
\titleformat{\section}%
  [hang]% shape
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}% format
  {}% label
  {0mm}% sep
  {%
    \vadjust pre{%
      \color{gray!50}%
      \hrule width \titlewidth height 4pt\relax
      \hrule width \linewidth height .4pt\relax
    }%
  }% before-code
\showoutput
\begin{document}

\section{A test section}

\mbox{}

\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\section{A test section}
Text text text
\section{A test section}

\end{document}
```

[image]